# Unable to get the value of an element in ironpython use powershell

Tags: powershell, ironpython

The following code needs to get the value of the element, but the output is empty

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\IronPython.dll")
$py = [ironpython.hosting.python]::CreateEngine()
$pyv = $py.CreateScope()
$pyc = $py.CreateScriptSourceFromString("d = {'one':1,'two':2}")
$pyc.Execute($pyv)
$d = $pyv.GetVariable("d")
$d.one
$d.two
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get("key")` function or `$variable["key"]` to get dictionary values :

```
$engine = [ironpython.hosting.python]::CreateEngine()
$pyv = $engine.CreateScope()
$pyc = $engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("d = {'one':1,'two':2}")
$pyc.Execute($pyv)
$d = $pyv.GetVariable("d")
$d.get("one")
$d["two"]
```

**This is the expected behavior with python dictionaries**,if you try `get-member` on the object then you can see that the properties one and two are not there but powershell won't throw error even if you try to access properties that are not there